# How to call HierarchicalDataSource.read() from kendoDropDownListchange event?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the treeview and HierarchicalDataSource of KendoUI. Plus on the top I also had a kendoDropDownList. Basically each time user change the dropdownlist value it trigger `change` event and HierarchicalDataSource will read again. But seem my dropdown change event not working as i expected? I did not call `HierarchicalDataSource.read().` Any idea what I doing wrong?

**Dropdownlist**

```js
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
  dataTextField: "functionName",
  dataValueField: "hrsPositionID",
  dataSource: {
  transport:{
    read: {
    url:  "./getDropdown.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: function() {
        return { 
          method: "getDropdown",
        }
      }
    },
  },
  },
  change: function(e){
    console.log(this.value());
    $('#AccountingTree').data('kendoTreeView').HierarchicalDataSource.read();  //<-- not working
  }
}).data('kendoDropDownList');
dropdownlist = $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

**HierarchicalDataSource & kendoTreeView**

```js
var serviceRoot = "./getyzdTreeView.php";   
dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: serviceRoot,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      data: function(){
        return {
          positionID: dropdownlist.value()  //read the value from dropdownlist 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id : "programID",
      hasChildren: false,
      children : "items"
    }
  },
  filter: { field: "module", operator: "startswith", value: "Accounting" }
});

$("#AccountingTree").kendoTreeView({
  check: onCheck,
  checkboxes: { checkChildren: true } ,
  dataSource: dataSource,
  dataBound: function(){
      this.expand('.k-item');
  },
  dataTextField: ["module","groupname","programName","checked"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Basically I just call

```
 change: function(e){
    dataSource.read()
 }
```